# Change cell text and other checkbox based on another checkbox

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure out following conditions via excel checkbox click (Refer the images attached)
[image]
[image]

After researching over Google, I am able to check and uncheck all sub-chckeboxes of cbx_1 via below code (Edited after commet of @user123677) -

```
Sub cbxGrp_Click()
    Dim oCbx As CheckBox
    Dim lValue As Long
    Dim sGrp As String
    sGrp = Application.Caller
    lValue = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(sGrp).Value
    sGrp = Split(sGrp, "_")(1)
    For Each oCbx In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
        If oCbx.Name Like "cbx_" & sGrp & "_*" Then
            oCbx.Value = lValue
        End If
    Next
    
    If lValue <> 1 Then
        Range("b2").Value = CVErr(xlErrNA)
        Range("B3").Value = False
        Range("B5").Value = False
        Range("B6").Value = False
    
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Now requirement is -

If I uncheck cbx_1_1 -

1. B2 = #N/A
2. B3, B5, B6 = FALSE
3. Rest will remain same
4. cbx_1_1_1 & cbx_1_1_2 checkboxes should be unchecked

Same logic for checkbox cbx_1_2. I am not very familiar with VBA scripting, so any help would be appreciated.

I have also uploaded the excel file [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iPcv1nIooDo69iuLHP-kxatH8VKnt_AN/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=117113287988872878818&rtpof=true&sd=true) to check directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could add this to your code

*Edit: after comment from @Pᴇʜ, thanks*

```
If lValue <> 1 Then
    Range("b2").Value = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    Range("b3").Value = False
    Range("b5").Value = False
    Range("b6").Value = False
    
End If
```

I haven't checked your code or made this the most efficient but for normal use this should be fine.

let me know how you get on :)

Comment: I highly recommend to use  `Range("b2").Value = CVErr(xlErrNA)` instead of `"#n/a"` to make sure the error is written and not a text!

Comment: Not worked. While clicking cbx_1_1, only B3 value changed. Hope I have added in correct area. Updated the code in actual one

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thanks, not come across that, have edited the answer to include.  Rituparno Bhattacharya is there any protection on the sheet or validation?  Try manually typing in False (same capitalisation) in B5 for example.  I cant see a reason why only one would work, all worked successfully on my test sheet.

Comment: I updated the code. This is added on cbx_1 checkbox. Is that fine? Or I need to add to other checkboxes also?

Comment: @RituparnoBhattacharya depends how you want it to update your sheet, if you want updates to happen when the other checkboxes are clicked then yes you will need to put this in their code as well.  also this only updates when the check box is unclicked as requested but doesn't change the text when it becomes clicked.

Comment: may be I am asking or demanding a silly thing. But as I am not familiar with VBA (as I am purely Infra Guy), is it possible to share full code where I can add what. Sorry may be I am asking a huge thing.

Comment: i guess the issue is I'm not certain what else you are trying to do.  in theory you can just assign those cells as control cells [right click clickbox -> format control -> control -> cell link] but you asked for B2 to be #n/a.  you can alter the code to have an else that sets everything to true. and then start clicking and unclicking check boxes to see what it does and whether that is the behaviour you need